# Non absolute counts histogram for imbalanced groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, facet-wrap

Currently, I can create the plot:
[image]

by using:

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes_string(age)) + 
  facet_wrap(~CUSTOMER_GROUP, scales="free") +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 3) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent) +
  theme_igray() +
  xlab("Age") +
  ylab("")
```

But as you see, this does not account for sensible percentage values. Is there a solution to this to get a more useful plot?
Note, I already use `scales="free"`

## edit

perhaps, it is also possible to format the scales more nicely without the `.00`

Comment: are you trying to visualize the relative frequencies instead of counts?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to accomplish

Comment: here's a sample: `ggplot(diamonds, aes(price, ..count../sum(..count..), group = cut, fill = cut)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 500)+
    facet_wrap(~cut, scales = 'free')`

Comment: LGTM. must check this out in a bit more detail -  though, `scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)` the only difference is that you are calculating the percentage value manually. Apparently - see my image above, this does not work well if different plots in the facet wrap are imbalanced in counts.

Comment: When trying it like `ggplot(diamonds, aes_string("price", ..count../sum(..count..), group = cut, colour = cut))` with `aes_string ` it does not work. As I need to execute this within a function I need to figure out a solution here for the non standard evaluation of the `..count..`

Comment: Actually `labels=` apparently just seems to refer to formatting (and not the desired transformation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to combine both methods:

```
scale_y_continuous(labels=percent) +
```

for nice visualization
and `..count../sum(..count..` for actual percentages.

To correctly work with `aes_string` in non standard evaluation mode `"..count../......"` simply quote the entire thing.